# Multiple IF clause within WHERE clause in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, if-statement

I have a table #t1 containing three columns, one of them named `root_symbol`.

I want to select all elements from table #t1 meeting the condition of variable `@root`.

However, variable `@root` can have four different values, thus I would like to dynamically select the filter applied by the `where` statement depending on the declared variable value.

```
declare @root integer
set @root = 1

select * from #t1
where root_symbol in
case when @root = 1 then ('ES')
        when @root = 2 then ('EW', 'EW1', 'EW2', 'EW3', 'EW4') 
        when @root = 3 then ('E1C', 'E2C', 'E3C', 'E4C', 'E5C') 
        when @root = 4 then ('E1A', 'E2A', 'E3A', 'E4A', 'E5A') 
end
```

I have seen this done using `case when`, however not with the value matching condition `in`.

An alternative would be to create an if statement with four different select statements inside, however also here I am not sure how to handle multi clause if statements in sql.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: `CASE` in T-SQL is an **expression** (like `a+b`) that can only return **one single, atomic** value - nothing else - no "list" of values or whatever you're trying to do here...

Answer (score 6):

Don't use `case`.  Use simple comparisons:

```
where (@root = 1 and root_symbol in ('ES')) or
      (@root = 2 and root_symbol in ('EW', 'EW1', 'EW2', 'EW3', 'EW4')) or
      (@root = 3 and root_symbol in ('E1C', 'E2C', 'E3C', 'E4C', 'E5C')) or 
      (@root = 4 and root_symbol in ('E1A', 'E2A', 'E3A', 'E4A', 'E5A'))
```

In general, use `case` expressions in the `where` clause is a bad idea (there are some exceptions).  Because the `case` forces the order of evaluation of its clauses, it prevents the optimizer from doing anything.